# Is this proof correct/complete?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}c_kx^k$ be a polynomial where $c_0$ and $c_n$ have different sings. Show $\exists x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0)=0$.

My workings so far: Lets assume $c_0>0$ and thus $c_n<0$. If this is not the case we can simply look at $f^*(x)=-f(x)$ and $f^*(x)$ will satisfy this condition where $f^*(x_0)=0$ implies $f(x_0)=0$. By this assumption we know $f(0)>0$. Then for sufficiently large $x_l$ we have:
$$|c_nx_l^n|>\left|\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}c_kx_l^k\right|$$
Therefore, as $c_n<0$, it follows that:
$$f(x_l)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}c_kx_l^k-|c_n|x_l^n<0$$
Now because $f(x)$ is a polynomial and therefore continuous, we can apply the intermediate value theorem to conclude that $\exists x_0 \in [0,x_l]$ such that $f(x_0)=0$.

Comment: Yes. Your instructor might want more details for the part "For sufficiently large $x_l$ we have...", but it looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed the part that I was worrying about. How do I make a statement like that more rigorous?

Comment: Intermediate value theorem, not mean value theorem.

Comment: Note that if $x_l >1$ you have $\left|\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}c_kx_l^k\right| \leq \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left|c_kx_l^k\right|< \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left|c_kx_l^{n-1}\right| < [\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left|c_k\right| ]x_l^{n-1}$. It is easy to make $|c_l|x_l^n$ larger than $[\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left|c_k\right| ]x_l^{n-1}$.

Comment: You don't show that the polynomial is $> 0$ at any point.

Comment: Yeah I showed that $f(0)>0$ because $c_0>0$.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier if you take the limit at $+\infty$.

Assume $c_0<0$ and $c_n>0$ first.

Then $f(0)=c_0<0$, while $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}c_nx^n=+\infty$.

So we can find $x>0$ such that $f(x)>0$.

By the intermediate value theorem, there exists  $x_0>0$ such that $f(x_0)=0$.

I let you do the case $c_0>0$ and $c_n<0$.